# javacript error when adding to a MMS/Taxonomy field in sharepoint online (ie11)

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have a brand new sharepoint online tenant. (actually I got the problem below, deleted the site collection and re-created it again). Im using csom (C#)

In the CA-->managed metadata I have created a TermSet with some Terms

In the site collection I programmatically created a Taxonomy Field, a content type, a list. I  added the field to the CT and the CT to the list...the usual drill.

Now, everything looks fine until I try to create a new row (list item), in the GUI and assign a value to the Taxonomy field. I get the selection-dialog and can add my terms. BUT when I click Ok in the selection-dialog I get a script error saying

> Line: 333 Error: Unable to get property 'set_returnValue' of undefined
>   or null reference

This only happens in, yes you guessed it...IE11.